# Pullback of a vector bundle on Abelian variety via $(-1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over some field $k$ and $(-1) : A \to A$ is the inverse map of $A$ as an algebraic group. If $V$ is a vector bundle over $A$ what is $(-1)^* V$? In other words, is there a way to describe $(-1)^* V$ in more standart functors? If it is not possible in general, what about special cases of $\operatorname{dim} A=1$ or $\operatorname{rk} V=1$?

For example, for elliptic curves, using Atiyah classification, it is easy to see that if $c_1(V)=0$ for some vector bundle $V$ then $(-1)^*(V) \cong V^*$. Is it true for higher dimensions?

Also, it is very interesting to understand $(-1)_*$, in particular, what is $(-1)_*\mathcal{O}$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure for general vector bundles, but for line bundles over $\mathbb{C}$, one knows by the Appel-Humbert Theorem that if $L$ is a line bundle on $A=\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$, then it is characterized by a positive definite Hermitian form $H:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ and a semi-character $\chi:\Lambda\to S^1$. One then has that $(-1)^*L(H,\chi)\simeq L(H,\chi^{-1})$ (see, for example, Birkenhake-Lange).

Comment: So, for $Pic^0(A)$ we have $(-1)^*L \cong L^*$. For other values of $c_1$ we get some involution on $Pic^d(A)$. What is this involution? Just taking inverse in the group $Pic^d(A)$?

Comment: Also, I'm very curious what is $(-1)_*\mathcal{O}$? Is there a way to understand this via Appel-Humbert?

Comment: Yes, $(-1)^*$ corresponds to the inverse in $\mbox{Pic}^H(A)$ for a hermitian form $H$, after you identify $\mbox{Pic}^H(A)$ with $\mbox{Pic}^0(A)$. Remember that $\mbox{Pic}^H(A)$ is not a subgroup of $\mbox{Pic}(A)$, since the addition map is of the form $\mbox{Pic}^H(A)\times\mbox{Pic}^{H'}(A)\to\mbox{Pic}^{H+H'}(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any morphism $f:X \to Y$ of varieties (or schemes), one has $f^*\mathcal O_Y = \mathcal O_X$.

---

A line bundle on an ellipitic curve of degree $d$ is of the form $\mathcal O(D)$ where $D = (d-1)O + P$, where $O$ is the origin and $P$ is a point on the curve.  Applying $[-1]^*$ takes this to $\mathcal O(D')$, where $D' = (d-1)O + (-P).$

Comment: According to the previous answer, degree is preserved, but what you described changes degree $d$ to $d-2$.

Comment: @Alex The $-P$ should be taken as the point $-P$, not the divisor $(-1)(P)$. So the degree of the point $-P$ on $E$ is 1.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth I see, thanks.